# Invalid Swift Support : SwiftSupport folder is missing error with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, xcode7

I am trying to upload an ipa with AdHoc distribution profile to iTunesConnect. My app is coded in Swift 2. My Xcode version is 7.0. The app gets uploaded without any errors. But after some time, I get a mail from Apple Developer on my Apple ID as follows :

***Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "TDGApp". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
Regards,
The App Store team***

I have set the flag Embedded content contains Swift to YES in Build Settings.

I can see the SwiftSupport folder in the archive(Show package contents) but I cannot see SwiftSupport folder in the ipa(payload). Because of this I am not able to upload my app to even AppStore. Please suggest some solutions.