# Xcode 7.2 Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode7.2, ios9.2

This might be some old issue already, but i've been working up for quite few days to fix this now. After submitting app to appstore i get this email :

```
Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
```

I've tried some suggestions as given in the similar questions at 
- [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559204/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-empty) - [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889599/xcode-7-0-1-invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing/35823892#35823892) - [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611258/invalid-swift-support-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing-error-with-xcode-7) and more

most of them suggested trying "Embedded content contains Swift" or update "command line tools" or try manual "framework" fix but none worked.

Anyone found the solution yet?

Comment: are you using Xcode 7.2, or Xcode 7.2.1 (which is today's current "master" version)?

Comment: am using xcode 7.2

does 7.2.1 has any related updates?

Comment: I dunno, but I was thinking that the error line "`Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.`" might mean something useful and you can rule out various potential issues.  7.2.1 is the current public GM version.

Comment: ok, i'll try using that now! Thanks!

Comment: but sadly that didnt work as well..

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I have the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318255/itunes-connect-this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421

Comment: none so far. am trying to redo the project again and see if i get something there. If you could point any helpful suggestions / ideas - that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used any `Swift` code in `Objective C` Project

then, go to `Build Settings` -> `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code` to `Yes` or vice-versa.

Then again archive your project and upload the new build to Appstore.

[image]