# iTunes connect: This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Note:
I am working on a Swift project with obj-c code.

I am getting this error when uploading to iTunes Connect:

> This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421)

Ok, then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421)

And then I get this in an email(this took a while to realise that error message is send via email :-) well just another day in the land of Xcode and iOS development):

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "my-app-name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild
>   your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit
>   it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Ok, then I set the "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" to YES.

Now after a day of wrestling with this, I am ?????

Comment: How do you generate your .ipa file? Probably I know how to help you :)

Comment: here is your answer :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the below message:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "my-app-name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild
>   your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit
>   it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

You need to upload your app using `Xcode Archive`.

```
Navigate to Xcode > Window > Organizer > Select your latest app archive > upload to App Store.
```

It's because when you upload app using apploader it doesn't contains `Swift Support`, but when you upload using archive it copy all the `swift` libraries into payload.

And make sure that you don't upload your build using any `Xcode` beta version.

Comment: Thanks Sohil, is this official knowledge?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? This is not a official knowledge but I have tried extracting `.xarchive` and `.app` which is generated and I found that `Swift` libraries are not added.

Comment: Ok, I see. I got it working as I got a more informal error message via Application Loader. It turned out that I had a library failing, which aligns ok with your answer. Thanks

Comment: But please make sure that if your application is built-up with `Swift` language then you must upload using Xcode archive.

Comment: I had the same error ( projects uses XCode 8, Swift 3 ), tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because internet connection issue with Apple's servers. Just wait and try later or next time. It will work, sure. It could also be your internet connection issue.

Facing this issue many times and It resolved automatically. There is nothing wrong with `xcode`. Try and try only solution for this.